# Conform colors between 2 RGB images in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv

i've two RGB images of the same subject with different color values...my goal is to conform colors and merge images. i've tried by converting RGB->HSV space and equalizing v channel, but the result is unsatisfactory. Some solutions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "conform"? Are we talking about color correction? What are you trying to achieve by "conforming the colors and merging the images"?

Comment: i want to merge images "equalizing" colors to avoid the merge effect. merge is made by drawing one image next another one.

Comment: The HSV colorspace models the very non-linear perception of color poorly.  Trying to merge colors is indeed not going to work well.  Use Lab instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert both images in to black and white and than scale the color pixel values ..in particular range and then start comparing it.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the histograms of both images. They should be the same, but they probably aren't (given the question).

To take a simple example, in one picture 50% of the blue values might be below 110, while in the other 50% are below 130. You then will want to convert 110 to 120 in the first image, and 130 to 120 in the second.

You'd want to do the same for 25% and 75%; depending on the actual differences you might want to partition the histograms in even smaller parts.

Remember to do this for all three histograms.